# How does Salesforce share the work from different users between trigger instance?

Tags: apex, trigger

Imagine I have 5 users working in a training on the same Sobject type (Parent__c). They all have a page where they can create 50 child objects (Child__c) with the single click of a button.

Assume there exits a Trigger for Child__c. We all now Triggers work bulkified for up to 200 records.

How does Salesforce share the work between trigger instance

- 5 trigger instance for 50 records each are fired
- 3 trigger instance for 200, 200, 50 records are fired

This is relevant to me because my trigger fires a Batch job to prevent Limit execptions from subsequent triggers. If each user gets his own instance (Case 1) I might run into the 5 Batches in Parallel Limit. But even in Case 2 if more than 1000 records are saved in parallel I will hit my limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am positive (based on my research and the feedback in the comments below) that these each are session based. As in, if 5 users save 50 records each, 5 triggers of 50 records each are run. My reasoning behind this thinking is:

- Triggers fire in bulk and have their own [Order of Execution](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)
- This Order of Execution includes multiple validation steps.
- If Salesforce bulked up these records it would cause massive problems with validation. Let me show you a scenario:

  - You have 5 users. User A, B, C, D, and E.
  - Users A, B, and C all have valid data.
  - Users D and E have invalid data.
  - In a bulk processing scenario, all 5 would get errors returned for invalid data because of the [transaction management](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm) of Triggers.
  - In a non-bulk processing scenario, User A, B, and C would process successfully. Users D and E would each receive separate errors on what is wrong in their record set.

I did a bit of research and I could not find any specific Salesforce documentation explaining this, but like I said, I am positive this is how it works (and in my opinion it makes sense to work like this because of transactions).

Comment: Sound like a good argumentation. Thanks Jesse. Maybe someone from Salesforce can confirm this officially ;)

Comment: Another thing to watch out for is if you are processing a single list from a single User, from Apex, with more than 200 records SF will batch it up as lists of 200 to the trigger, so `update listOfSize1001` will call the trigger 6 times (200 x 5 + 1 x 1).

Comment: Consider what UserInfo.getUserId() returns in a trigger if multiple users data is processed in the same context.

Comment: Acuariano: Can you elaborate a bit what you mean?

Comment: The UserInfo object runs in context for each individual user - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm - If your trigger accesses UserInfo (which is perfectly valid), it should return different values for each user. This means that the trigger must run separately for each user. I think that definitively proves the trigger runs separately for each request.

Comment: Each API call/apex invocation has it's own transaction on the underlying database and doesn't share any part of this state with other API calls/apex invocations. Multiple users and multiple actions will never share state outside of 1) viewstate and 2) the database.

Comment: > `Triggers fire in bulk and have their own Order of Execution`

Does "bulk" mean parallel here?